# How to make a list out of a file with words?

Tags: python, list, file

I have a file `words.py`, with almost 60.000 words, one on every line. How can i store all these words as one big list?

I know i can make a list by iterating through the file, but this takes too long, and I will have to do this every time i run the program, so I am looking for a way to easily do it manually

Is there a keyboards shortcut for wrapping all the words in `" ",`, or is there another easy way to make a list out of these words? (I am using Visual Studio Code)

Comment: One way or another, you'll have to read that much data into memory from a file. Either that will be you, from a plaintext file, or a Python interpreter from the source file. In any case, reading 60k lines is peanuts if implemented correct, how exactly are you doing it, and how long does it take?

Comment: the way i currently do it is by reading the file as .txt:
`f = open("words.txt", 'r')
words = []
for x in f:
    words.append(x) 
f.close()`
I am just wondering if there is any way i could declare all the words as a list variable and import them into my code

Comment: You can write a simple script to do that conversion, but it won't make the program any faster, if you're now reading the file only once.

Comment: For repetitive tasks like this, I'd import the text file into Notepad++ and Start Macro and fix up the lines as you'd like. Then Repeat Macro to end of file.